# XCode 15 reporting some <private> warnings

Tags: xcode

I just updated to xcode 15 a few days ago and in one of my apps, I am getting a purple warning that simply says .

Here is a sample of one function reporting this error;

```
class SettingsTabController: NSTabViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var tabHeader: NSTabView!
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do view setup here.
        if #available(macOS 11, *) {
            tabHeader.tabViewType = .noTabsNoBorder
        } else {
            tabHeader.tabViewType = .topTabsBezelBorder
        }
        
    }
    
}
```

The super.viewDidLoad() is the line that is triggering the error. I also have it showing on instantiating a view controller from within an objc function as well.

Is there any way to get more information on what the issue is?

Comment: Says what? Can you edit your question and show what the error is?

Comment: @jvarela. That is literally all it shows <private>. Nothing else.

Comment: @Ryan_H Have you tried to rebuild your app after cleaning your Build folder?